# Terminal text size different when connected to external monitor

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, terminal, display, font

I have a Macbook Pro 15" running OS X 10.6.8. When not connected to an external monitor, launching Terminal looks like this. Note the width of the text (almost looks bold).
[image]
When connected to my 24" Dell 2408WFP monitor (via Mini DisplayPort to DVI connector), launching Terminal looks like this. Note the skinny non-bold appearance of the text.
[image]
Even more odd is Terminal decides on the text style depending on **when** the app was first launched. If Terminal was initially launched with no external monitor connected, it uses the bold style. If I keep Terminal open and hot connect to my Dell monitor, all subsequent new Terminal windows will use the bold style. If I exit Terminal and relaunch, it uses the skinny non-bold text.

This behavior is really annoying as I prefer the non-external monitor bold appearance.

Oddly, at work I have an iMac connected to a 24" Apple Cinema Display and all Terminal instances uses the bold style text. I suspect Terminal on startup is detecting the monitor(s) and doing something to the text style.

Is there anyway to disable this behavior?

**Follow-Up:** I'm seeing this behavior in other applications such as iTerm and Firefox. I suspect it's a operation system issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some searching, this appears to be a known issue. OS X somehow isn't fully aware my Dell monitor, and is not applying the same font smoothing. The font smoothing can be set using:

```
defaults -currentHost write -globalDomain AppleFontSmoothing -int 2
```

See this [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/100121/why-do-fonts-sometimes-look-fat-on-mac-os-x) and [macrumors](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=774761) threads.